# How to Change Elements Before & After Navbar Collapse?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am trying to change a few elements in the navbar on a website. At first, when a user hovers over a link, it will add a border below the link (to indicate that the user is hovering over it), like so:

[image: Before, no navbar collapse]
The navbar is transparent at the top of the page.

And when the user scrolls down the page, the navbar will collapse (if that's the right term?), and look like this:

[image: After, collapsed navbar]

The problem is that I do not want the bottom border to appear when the navbar is collapsed. How do I fix this with CSS?

Here is the HTML I have:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class=container>
        <div class="navbar-header page-scroll">
          <button type=button class=navbar-toggle data-toggle=collapse data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <span class=sr-only>Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class=icon-bar></span>
          <span class=icon-bar></span>
          <span class=icon-bar></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand page-scroll" href="#page-top"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class=hidden>
              <a href="#page-top"></a>
            </li>
            <li class=main-links>
              <a class=page-scroll href="#about">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class=main-links>
              <a class=page-scroll href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a>
            </li>
            <li class=main-links>
              <a class=page-scroll href="#contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
            <li class=dropdown-bar>
              <a href=""> More &#9660;</a>
              <ul class=drop-nav>
                <a href=""><li>Blog</li></a>
                <a href=""><li>Resources</li></a>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Along with the CSS for the navbar:

```
.navbar-default {
    border-color: transparent;
    background-color: #222;
}

/* Name in top left corner */
.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    font-family: Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    color: white;
}

/* Hover over name in left corner */
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:active,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand.active {
    color: #888;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
    border-color: rgba(255,255,255,.02);
}

/* Navbar button color */
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #bf0a0a;
    background-color: #bf0a0a;
}


/* Navbar icon color */
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #bf0a0a;
}

.navbar-default .nav li a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #fff;
}

/* Hover over [About, Portfolio, Contact, More] */
.navbar-default .nav > .main-links a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav > .main-links a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    outline: 0;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s;
    -moz-transition: all .4s;
    transition: all .4s;
}

/* Hover over [More] */
.navbar-default .nav > .dropdown-bar a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav > .dropdown-bar a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    outline: 0;
}


.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a {
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #bf0a0a;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #407EB0;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    .navbar-default {
        padding: 25px 0;
        border: 0;
        background-color: transparent;
        -webkit-transition: padding .3s;
        -moz-transition: padding .3s;
        transition: padding .3s;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
        font-size: 2em;
        -webkit-transition: all .3s;
        -moz-transition: all .3s;
        transition: all .3s;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a {
        border-radius: 3px;
    }

    .navbar-default.navbar-shrink {
        padding: 10px 0;
        background-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.8);
    }

    .navbar-default.navbar-shrink .dropdown-bar:hover > .drop-nav {
        display: block;
        margin-top: 10%;
        padding-right: 100%;
        background-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 0.8);
    }

    .navbar-default.navbar-shrink .navbar-brand {
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }
}
```

The CSS that adds the border specifically when hovering is here:

```
/* Hover over [About, Portfolio, Contact, More] */
.navbar-default .nav > .main-links a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav > .main-links a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    outline: 0;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #fff;
    -webkit-transition: all .4s;
    -moz-transition: all .4s;
    transition: all .4s;
}
```

Javascript that handles page-scrolling and navbar change:

```
var cbpAnimatedHeader = (function() {

    var docElem = document.documentElement,
        header = document.querySelector( '.navbar-default' ),
        didScroll = false,
        changeHeaderOn = 300;

    function init() {
        window.addEventListener( 'scroll', function( event ) {
            if( !didScroll ) {
                didScroll = true;
                setTimeout( scrollPage, 250 );
            }
        }, false );
    }

    function scrollPage() {
        var sy = scrollY();
        if ( sy >= changeHeaderOn ) {
            classie.add( header, 'navbar-shrink' );
        }
        else {
            classie.remove( header, 'navbar-shrink' );
        }
        didScroll = false;
    }

    function scrollY() {
        return window.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop;
    }

    init();

})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user scrolls down the page, `navbar-shrink` is added to the navbar, which overrides some of the styles from `navbar-default`. Likewise, you can override the default hover behaviour by using this code underneath the default hover code.

```
.navbar-shrink .nav > .main-links a:hover,
.navbar-shrink .nav > .main-links a:focus {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Comment: Hi. OK. I think I get what you're saying, but what do you mean by adding a class to them when they're collapsed? What exactly should I change in the HTML?

Comment: @FreddieV4 well, how does your navbar get into "collapsed mode" right now?

Comment: How? When the user scrolls down past the header of the page

Comment: @FreddieV4 yeah, I get that. But something has to happen in the code for that change to happen when they scroll. If I had to guess, I'd say there is some javascript that keeps track of your scroll position and then when it gets to a certain point, it adds a class to your navbar that changes the way it looks. Can you create an example at http://codepen.io/pen/ ?

Comment: So, according to the `js` file I have, the class that gets added to the navbar is `navbar-shrink` and it gets added to `navbar-default` (I pasted the js above). So should it be... 

`/* Hover over [About, Portfolio, Contact, More] */
.navbar-default .nav > .main-links .navbar-shrink a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav > .main-links .navbar-shrink a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: none;
}` ?

Comment: No, because .navbar-shrink is not contained within .main-links, so the selector `.main-links .navbar-shrink` doesn't refer to anything. The format would probably work like this: `.navbar-shrink .nav > .main-links a:hover` and  `.navbar-shrink .nav > .main-links a:active` If for some reason it doesn't, you can try using `border-bottom: none !important;` I'll fix my answer.